# Assign found value, from a range, to variable

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I want to grab a unique value from Outlook mail, look for that value in a column of an Excel file, and return an associated value.

I am working with the `.find` function from the Excel library to lookup my unique value. `find` is supposed to return a range of the first occurrence of my value but I cannot assign that value to the variable: pointer.

How can I reference it?

```vb
Sub OTM1S() '(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pointer As Range
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("I:\referencefile.xlsx")

    'On Error Resume Next
    pointer = wb.Sheets("Bonds").Range("A1:A10000").Find("XS1058142081")
    MsgBox pointer.Offset(0, 1)
    'On Error GoTo 0
 
    wb.Save
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you are trying to set an object reference you need the `Set` keyword.  Try this:

```
Sub OTM1S() '(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim pointer As Range
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("I:\referencefile.xlsx")

    'On Error Resume Next
    Set pointer = wb.Sheets("Bonds").Range("A1:A10000").Find("XS1058142081")
    MsgBox pointer.Offset(0, 1)
    'On Error GoTo 0

    wb.Save
    wb.Close

End Sub
```

You should also handle the scenario where the reference is not found.  This can be done like so:

```
Set pointer = wb.Sheets("Bonds").Range("A1:A10000").Find("XS1058142081")
If Not pointer Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox pointer.Offset(0,1)
Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, couldn't find that in the specified range."
End If
```